# Display Text on MFC Based Application

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I'm a little new to using MFC and VC++ as such, but I'm doing this as part of a Course and i Have to stick to VC++.

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/game_programming/same_game_part1.html

This is the tutorial I have been following to make a simple samegame. However when i try to display score, the score is getting displayed Underneath or outside my application window, even though I've displayed score before calling updateWindow(). I've tried various methods but I am kinda lost here.

Here is the code I'm using to Display the score:

```
void CSameGameView::updateScore()
{
CSameGameDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
CRect rcClient, rcWindow;
GetClientRect(&rcClient);
GetParentFrame()->GetWindowRect(&rcWindow);

int nHeightDiff = rcWindow.Height() - rcClient.Height();

rcScore.top=rcWindow.top + pDoc->GetHeight() * pDoc->GetRows() + nHeightDiff;
rcScore.left=rcWindow.left + 50;
rcScore.right=rcWindow.left + pDoc->GetWidth() - 50;
rcScore.bottom=rcScore.top + 20;

CString str;
double points = Score::getScore();
str.Format(_T("Score: %0.2f"), points);

HDC hDC=CreateDC(TEXT("DISPLAY"),NULL,NULL,NULL);
COLORREF clr = pDoc->GetBoardSpace(-1, -1); //this return background colour

pDC->FillSolidRect(&rcScore, clr);
DrawText(hDC, (LPCTSTR) str, -1, (LPRECT) &rcScore, DT_CENTER);
}
```

Thank you for any help and I'm sorry if the question doesn't make sense or in ambiguous.

Comment: What happens if you hard-code `rcScore.top` to some value you know to be within your window? For instance `rcScore.top = 100;`

Comment: @olevegard then it doesn't show. From trial and error, i've found out that the score is displayed behind what is there on the window. In this case, the game screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

1. The hDC you are creating is going to have coordinates relative to the desktop window.  To paint text in your window, use CClientDC like this: CClientDC dc(this); (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/s8kx4w44%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

2.  The code you have will leak a DC every time the function is called.  The method in #1 will fix that.

3.  Your paint code should be done in the CView::OnDraw.  There you get a DC passed to you and you don't have to worry about creating one with CClientDC.  Set the variables you want to draw (e.g. your points or score), store them as class members and draw them in CView::OnDraw.
Don't do the drawing in your updateScore method.
Make sense?  Hang in there!

Comment: I tried what you suggested. 

But now I end up having a the score displaying somewhere near the center my window. And it changes its position every time I move my Main window anywhere. I would like to have it fixed in one spot so that it doesn't come in the way as such.

Comment: I'm not sure about your exact application, but start with putting the rcScore.top at something like 50 and see how it looks, rather than doing the calculations you are doing.   If it is a scroll view, however, you will have to adjust the top for the amount it is scrolled down, etc.  Does that help?

Comment: Have a look at the link, the picture there is basically what my screen looks like. I'm just trying to add the score function to that. The calculations made, I've used to resize the initial window to my working screen so i'm pretty sure they work.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: No matter how much i mess around with the rcScore values, the score just keeps jumping around every time I move the window. Could it be possible because of the DC?

Comment: Could you list the relevant code in your CView::OnDraw so I can see exactly what you are doing?

Comment: Its a little bit over the length limit. How do i show it to you?

Comment: Just list the relevant part where you are trying to display the text

Comment: `CClientDC hDC(this);
  DrawText(hDC, (LPCTSTR) str, -1, (LPRECT) &rcWindow, DT_LEFT|DT_TOP);`
thats what i use to display the text. I had to switch from rcScore to rcWindow as rcScore wasnt giving me any output. rcWindow is the rectangle for the entire Window.

Comment: `for(int row = 0; row < pDoc->GetRows(); row++)
  {
    for(int col = 0; col < pDoc->GetColumns(); col++)
    {
      clr = pDoc->GetBoardSpace(row, col);
      CRect rcBlock;
      rcBlock.top = row * pDoc->GetHeight();
      rcBlock.left = col * pDoc->GetWidth();
      rcBlock.right = rcBlock.left + pDoc->GetWidth();
      rcBlock.bottom = rcBlock.top + pDoc->GetHeight();
      //  Fill in the block with the correct color
      pDC->FillSolidRect(&rcBlock, clr);
      //  Draw the block outline
      pDC->Rectangle(&rcBlock);
    }
  }`
Thats what i use to draw my Screen.